# missing libjpeg.so.62 from ia32 shared library

Tags: installation, 64-bit, libraries

I am trying to install a chemical/molecular biology modeling program called Molsoft ICM-Pro.  Initially after downloading the program and trying to open, it gave me error messages that I was missing shared libraries, and after talking with my network administrator he recommended I install the ia32 shared libraries using

> sudo apt-get install ia32-libs

Which gives

> sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
>   Reading package lists... Done
>   Building dependency tree
>   Reading state information... Done
>   ia32-libs is already the newest version.
>   0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

so I am assuming the libraries installed correctly, but now when I try to run the program I get this error:

> ubuntu:/home/reilly/icmd> icm
>   icm: error while loading shared libraries: libjpeg.so.62: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

So my question is, where can I get the library containing libjpeg.so.62?

Additionally, I was told I would need libXmu.so.6 and libtiff.so.3 .    Is there a shared library that could be missing that would contain these files?  I am an ubuntu noob, so sorry if the information I provided was unclear.

Any help would be immensely appreciated!

btw I am using ubuntu 12.04 dual boot with windows on an HP pavilion dv6

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install libjpeg62:i386
```

For other libraries, the same applies but find the correct name of the package providing the specific library. The ":i386" suffix tells Ubuntu to install the 32 bit version of the library (i386 architecture) because your architecture is 64 bits and by default it would install packages for it.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up installing the other libraries and for some reason the program was looking for libtiff.so.3 rather than the updated libtiff.so.4, so I created a symlink from 3 to 4 and that seemed to do the trick!